# How to implement dynamic UI element configuration based on ComboBox selection in an MVVM-friendly way in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF app which defines a simple `StackPanel` containing a drop down, some checkboxes and a `TextBlock` element:

[image]

The XAML might look like this:

```xml
<StackPanel>
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownChoices}" SelectedItem="{Binding DropDownSelected}"/>
  <CheckBox Content="First Item" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBox1IsChecked }"/>
  <CheckBox Content="Second Item" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBox2IsChecked}"/>
  <CheckBox Content="Third Item" IsChecked="{Binding CheckBox3IsChecked}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBlockContent}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The data context `MainViewModel` might look something like this:

```cs
class MainViewModel
{
   public List<string>? DropDownChoices { get; set; }

   public string? DropDownSelected { get; set; }
   public bool CheckBox1IsChecked { get; set; }
   public bool CheckBox2IsChecked { get; set; }
   public bool CheckBox3IsChecked { get; set; }
   public string? TextBlockContent { get; set; }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
   }
}
```

I would like to find an MVVM-friendly way of achieving the following:

- `DropDownChoice1` is selected

  - Check the first item
  - Modify the text content of the `TextBlock` to `the first drop down is selected`
- `DropDownChoice2` is selected

  - Check the second and third items
  - Modify the text content of the `TextBlock` to `the second drop down is selected`

One way to do this is as follows:

- implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- call `OnPropertyChanged` on all check box element setters
- Modify the `DropdownSelected` property setter as follows:

```cs
public string? DropDownSelected
{
   get => m_dropDownSelected;
   set
   {
      Console.WriteLine("DropDownSelected set");
      m_dropDownSelected = value;

      if (m_dropDownSelected == "DropDownChoice1")
      {
         CheckBox1IsChecked = true;
         CheckBox2IsChecked = false;
         CheckBox3IsChecked = false;
         TextBlockContent = "Drop down choice 1 is selected";
      }
      else
      {
         CheckBox1IsChecked = false;
         CheckBox2IsChecked = true;
         CheckBox3IsChecked = true;
         TextBlockContent = "Drop down choice 2 is selected";
      }
   }
}
```

However, imagine a use case where there are dozens of checkboxes, text blocks and other UI elements that depend on the combo box selected item in this way. Furthermore, suppose that the combo box makes more than two choices available, where each choice has its own distinct configuration for the dependent UI elements.

In such a scenario, the if statement in the `DropdownSelected` property setter would become quite large, with each choice representing an `else if` branch, and with dozens of properties being set in each branch. Adding a new drop down choice with a different configuration, or a new UI element dependent upon such a choice would become a maintenance nightmare.

What is the most idiomatic, MVVM-friendly and extensible way of achieving this effect in WPF, without resorting to bloated setters in my `DropdownSelected` property?

Answer (score 1):

There is no MVVM-firendly way of writing code - only a clean way of writing code.

> If a method gets too long refactor it into multiple small methods.

```cs
private string? m_dropDownSelected;
public string? DropDownSelected
{
    get => m_dropDownSelected;
    set
    {
        m_dropDownSelected = value;
        OnDropDownSelected( value );
    }
}

private void OnDropDownSelected( string? value )
{
    switch ( value )
    {
        case "DropDownChoice1":
            OnDropDownChoice1();
            break;
        case "DropDownChoice2":
            OnDropDownChoice2();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private void OnDropDownChoice1()
{
    CheckBox1IsChecked = true;
    CheckBox2IsChecked = false;
    CheckBox3IsChecked = false;
    TextBlockContent = "Drop down choice 1 is selected";
}

private void OnDropDownChoice2()
{
    CheckBox1IsChecked = false;
    CheckBox2IsChecked = true;
    CheckBox3IsChecked = true;
    TextBlockContent = "Drop down choice 2 is selected";
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds a bit rude, but your answer completely misses the point. As I mentioned in my question, suppose I wanted to add an additional checkbox. I would have to specify it in every method you propose. Suppose I wanted to add a new drop down item. I'd have to add all the bound properties in this new method and set their values. Your suggestion arguably makes the code even harder to maintain IMO.

Comment: It addresses *In such a scenario, the if statement in the DropdownSelected property setter would become **quite large**, with each choice representing an else if branch, and with dozens of properties being set in each branch.* - adding more affected options will produce more code in any way, so there is no best of

Comment: Right, but the size of the setter is not the only issue here. I'm ultimately looking for a more flexible and extensible way to add new dropdown options along with a default UI configuration. One possible solution is to dynamically switch the main view's `DataContext` with a new view model with the bound properties initialized to the correct default values, but that would break MVVM.

Comment: There are multiple ways, but you will face the same problems when adding more affected options. Even with a new viewmodel instance for each case you have to set the options/add the new options for each case and not easier to maintain then this. So in all this question is opinion based and I already voted to close it.